# An order relation

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Suppose that $\pi:C^{'} \rightarrow C$ is a double unramified cover of a riemann surface of genus $g>0$.
Let $\tau:C^{'} \rightarrow C$ the involution sheet exanche and suppose that $f$ is a meromorphic funtion on $C^{'}$ that is anti-invarian respect to $\tau$ i.e. $f=-f\circ \tau$.
Is there a relation between the order of $f$ in the point $p\in C^{'}$ ($ord_{p}(f)$) and the order of the function $-f \circ \tau$   ($ord_{p}(-f\circ \tau)$)?
What can i say? For example i would say that $ord_{p}(f)=-ord_{p}(f \circ \tau)$. Is this relation valid?

Comment: Let me be sure I understand --- you assume that the functions $f$ and $-f \circ \tau$ are *equal*, and you are asking if their orders at a point are related?

Comment: i know that the order are equal but i'm asking if i can exanche the relation such in the way that i've written or in other ways. I'm searching a way to express $ord_{p}(-f\circ \tau)$ using soe order properties

Comment: for example the raltion $ord(-f \circ \tau)=-ord_{p}(f\circ \tau)$. And is there a way to change $ord_{p}(-f\circ \tau)$ without using $\tau$?

Comment: You are asking two different things. The first is "Is there are relation between the order of $f$ and the order of $-f \circ \tau$?" Since those are **the same function**, the answer should be completely clear! The second is whether the order of $-f \circ \tau$ at a point is the _negative_ of the order of $f \circ \tau$. The answer to that is *no*. What are the orders of the functions $x$ and $-x$ at the origin in \mathbf C?

Comment: they are the same. so i can write $ord_{p}(-f \circ \tau)=ord_{p}(f \circ \tau)$

Comment: i think that $\tau$ switch zeros with zeros and poles with poles just bacause $f$ is antinvariant. So Is it true that the zero divisor of $f$ $(f)_{0}$ is equal to the zero divisor of $(f\circ \tau)$?